# How can I fire JQuery functions sequentially with deferred()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really having trouble wrapping my head around the deferred() method inside jquery. I've spent several hours reading the documentation, but I still don't fully understand what I'm doing.

My basic problem is, I have a series of functions (not ajax calls) that I want to run in sequence, but stop all processes if there is an error in any of them.

Here is how far I've gotten (I've stripped out a bunch of unneeded code and just left the basic idea)

```
//The module  var myModule = (function() {

//Defaults
var vOne;
var VTwo;
var deferred = $.Deferred();

//Private method
var _myPrivateFunction1 = function(userID) {
    if(userID >= 10) {
        //All is good, set var vOne to true and run next function
        vOne = true;
        return deferred.promise();
    } else {
        //User is not allowed, stop everything else and show the error message
        return deferred.reject();
    }
}

var _myPrivateFunction2 = function() {
    if(vOne === true) {
        //Ok we can keep going
        return deferred.promise();
    } else {
        //again stop everything and throw error
        return deferred.reject();
    }
};

var _myPrivateFunction3 = function(element) {
    //...and so on
};


var _errorMsgFunction = function(msg) {
    $.log("There was an error: " + msg);
    return false;
};


//Public method
var myPublicFunction = function(element,call) {
    //element is jquery object passed through user "click" event
    var userID = element.data('id')
    var userAction = element.data('action');

    //Now... i want to fire _myPrivateFunction1, _myPrivateFunction2, _myPrivateFunction3 in sequence and STOP all processes, and run 
    // _errorMsgFunction if there is an error in any of them.
    //This is how far I've gotten...

    _myPrivateFunction1(userID).then(_myPrivateFunction2(userAction), _errorMsgFunction("Error in _myPrivateFunction2")).then(_myPrivateFunction3(element),_errorMsgFunction("Error in _myPrivateFunction3")).fail(_errorMsgFunction("Error in _myPrivateFunction1"));

};

// Public API
return {
    myPublicFunction: myPublicFunction
};
})();
```

So right now I  keep getting "Error in _myPrivateFunction2" (I'm forcing this error for testing purposes), but the other functions after continue to fire...They don't stop. What am I missing here?

Comment: Using defered is considered a anti-pattern. See [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot share deferred objects. You should create a different promise from a deferred for each function.

Here is some very simple example, using sycnhronus functions for the sake of simplicity, although promises are meant to be used with asynchronous functions:

```
var func1 = function(arg){
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    if (arg === 0) {
        dfd.resolve('func1 Ok');
    } else {
        dfd.reject('func1 arg != 0');
    }
    return dfd.promise();
}

var func2 = function(arg){
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    if (arg === 0) {
        dfd.resolve('func2 Ok');
    } else {
        dfd.reject('func2 arg != 0');
    }
    return dfd.promise();
}

var func3 = function(arg){
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    if (arg === 0) {
        dfd.resolve('func3 Ok');
    } else {
        dfd.reject('func3 arg != 0');
    }
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

If the functions does not depend on other to do their processing, we can do it in parallel using `jQuery.when`

```
// Parallel processing

jQuery.when(func1(1), func2(0), func3(0)).then(function(res1, res2, res3){
    console.log(res1, res2, res3);
}).fail(function(reason){
    console.error(reason); // will fail with reason func1 arg != 0
});
```

If it is a sequence processing (as I undertood your problem is), you should do:

```
// Sequential processing

func1(0).then(function(res1){
    return func2(res1);
}).then(function(res2){
    return func3(res2);
}).then(function(res3){
    // everything ran ok, so do what you have to do...
}).fail(function(reason){
    console.log(reason);
});
```

The code above will fail with reason:

```
> func2 arg != 0
```

If you have mixed parallel and sequential processing to do, then you should mix both approaches.

---

### Disclaimer

As in my example, if `func1` or `func2` have side effects, they will not be undone within `fail()` by themselves.

The best practice is to only have side effects when you are absolutely sure that everything went ok, that is, inside the last `then()` call.

Comment: +1! Maybe you should add a notice though that in general deferreds/promises should not be used in synchronous functions like those in the example.

Comment: I feel like I'm still missing a component to fully grasp this concept. First of all, you are 100% right, my example is rubbish because I don't need defer anything if I'm not using AJAX, because all my functions are running synchronously anyway. But, is there another way of explaining what func1(0).then(function(res1){
    return func2(res1);
}) does? What exactly is happening here? You run func1, you pass 0 as arg, then the function runs, sends back what? A string? Object? And now what is function(res1)? why is is wrapping return func2(res1)? And lastly, what is the return in this case doing?

Comment: Rule of thumb: `promise.then` always return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a separate `$.deferred()` inside each of your functions, because you want to return unique promise for each function.

```
//Private method
var _myPrivateFunction1 = function(userID) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if(userID >= 10) {
        //All is good, set var vOne to true and run next function
        vOne = true;
        deferred.resolve();
    } else {
        //User is not allowed, stop everything else and show the error message
        deferred.reject();
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Then your public function should work.